# Redraw/Update Y-axis only

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Is it possible to update/redraw/change only the Y axis values dynamically?  For example, I have a spectrum analyzer where my X-axis remains the same once the chart is drawn but I'd like continuously update the Y-axis values without having to redraw the entire chart.
updateOptions({ file: data }) is almost what I'm looking for however it's redrawing over whats already graphed.  For example, if my array contains 100 elements, first draw is correct, second update draws a line from 100 back to 0 and graphs my values again.
Pretty sure I'm overlooking something simple.

[image]

Comment: if its not moving on the x axis, you would just be drawing a straight line up and down

Comment: Is your data sorted? dygraphs requires that it be sorted and will draw odd lines like this if it's not (it'll warn you on the JS console if it's not sorted)

Comment: Thanks danvk, that was what my issue.